# C#: How to check if all the elements in an array of boolean variables are of the same value (All true or All false)?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of boolean variables and I want to return true if all the elements in this array are of the same value, false otherwise. I know I can loop through all the elements, but I'm wondering if there are any faster ways in C#.

Comment: Any method you use boils down to checking every element; there's no way around that. Loop over the elements and return false if any element doesn't match the first one.

Comment: imo prprcupofcoffee's approach is the fastest, exiting the loop makes it the fastest

Answer (score 7):

```
var allAreTheSame = myArray.All(a => a) || myArray.All(a => !a)
```

Comment: This is not faster than the solution proposed by the OP

Comment: @dcastro If as soon as All hits a member that does not satisfy the predicate it stops iterating, so yes it is.

Comment: Assuming his proposal didn't include that check - he was overly vague. But, fair enough.

Answer (score 6):

```
var result = array.Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

Comment: @Ani a distinct on boolean values will never return more than 2 values.

Comment: Er, yes. Brainfreeze.

Comment: @JimMischel - `Distinct().Count()` is `0` for an empty array so this will return false.

Comment: @Lee I think determining if all elements are the same makes no sense on an array without elements. I think that situation should be handled by a seperate code path.

Comment: @MarkO - It does make sense and should return true, the same as `Enumerable.All` does on an empty collection. If it really is an error in this application it should throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Assuming the array is NOT empty
// Get first value
var firstValue = myArray.First();

// Check if all other values are identical
var allidentical = myArray.Skip(1).All(z => z == firstValue);
```

Comment: Most efficient and you could just add a quick one time check at the beginning.  Most of the other solutions loop over the array twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length-1).All(i => array[i] == array[i+1])
```

Edit: Fix after comments

```
Enumerable.Range(1, array.Length).All(i => array[i] == array[0])
```

Comment: This throws an exception on an empty array.

Comment: True. Enumerable.Range(1, array.Length).All(i => array[i] == array[0]) then.

Comment: That will still throw when you try to access index 0 of the array.

Comment: If the array is empty or has 1 element, the All(...) will not be evaluated

Comment: If the array is empty, then `Enumerable.Range` will throw since the count is negative.

Comment: In the answer, yes. Not in the fix I posted in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
var allAreTheSame = myArray.Distinct().Count() == 1
```

Just an alternative to David's approach, slightly shorter and possibly more efficient since I think the enumerator combination will cause the Array to be looped only once.

Comment: have a look at @MarkO's answer

Answer (score 0):

I would go for an extension method. I'd always love those methods:

The class containing the extension method will be:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool AreAll<T>(this T[] source, Func<T, bool> condition)
    { return source.Where(condition).Count() == source.Count(); }

    public static bool AreAllTheSame<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    { return source.Distinct().Count() == 1; }
}
```

You see that I have 2 extension methods, one taking a Func and one taking no parameter.

The first one is called when you want to check if all the elements in the array has the same value (for example, all elements are true, or all elements are false).

The second one is called, when you don't want to check against a specific parameter, but if you just want to see if all the values are the same.

And than a little demo to demonstrate the extension method itself:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool[] array = { true, false, true, false, true };
        bool[] trueArray = { true, true, true, true };

        Console.WriteLine("Searching with a predicate:");
        Console.WriteLine(array.AreAll(x => x).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(array.AreAll(x => !x).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(trueArray.AreAll(x => x).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(trueArray.AreAll(x => !x).ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("Searching without a predicate:");
        Console.WriteLine(array.AreAllTheSame().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(array.AreAllTheSame().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(trueArray.AreAllTheSame().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(trueArray.AreAllTheSame().ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This will produce the following output:

[image]
Let's hope it helps.

Comment: That's just a less-general implementation of `Enumerable.All` and a re-implementation of `Array.TrueForAll`. This still doesn't help since you need the first value to use in the predicate.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: I've adapted the code and the example. Providing 2 functions right now that are working on an IEnumerable. One that takes a predicate, the other one that works without a predicate.

Comment: Correct, there's no check on it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun a little different solution:

```
!(array.Any(b => b) && array.Any(b => !b));
```

There are two loops here.  One of them should exit on the first element in the array.  The other one should exit on the first occurrence that is different from the first in the array.  It will also return true for empty arrays.